# Laravel 5. 2 and DropZone Multiple Image Upload

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, dropzone

I have a problem in uploading images to a folder in Laravel 5.2 with DropzoneJs. I want to get the file object so that I can call methods on the file object in Laravel controller but the JavaScript code that I have returns the actual file name to the controller when I dump and die(dd).

```
create.blade.php

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ url('save') }}">

    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12 {{ $errors->has('document') ? 'has-error': '' }}">
        <label for="documents">Documents</label>
        <div class=" needsclick dropzone" id="document-dropzone">

        </div><br>
        @if($errors->has('document'))
            <span class="help-block">
              {{ $errors->first('document') }}
            </span>
            @endif
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="submit_button">&nbsp;</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
<script>
  var uploadedDocumentMap = {}
  Dropzone.options.documentDropzone = {
    url: '{{ url("storeMedia") }}',
    maxFilesize: 2, // MB
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    maxFiles: 3,
    maxFiles: 5,
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
    },
    success: function (file, response) {
      $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="document[]" value="' + response.name + '">')
      uploadedDocumentMap[file.name] = response.name
    },
    removedfile: function (file) {
      file.previewElement.remove()
      var name = ''
      if (typeof file.file_name !== 'undefined') {
        name = file.file_name
      } else {
        name = uploadedDocumentMap[file.name]
      }
      $('form').find('input[name="document[]"][value="' + name + '"]').remove()
    },
    init: function () {
      @if(isset($project) && $project->document)
        var files =
          {!! json_encode($project->document) !!}
        for (var i in files) {
          var file = files[i]
          this.options.addedfile.call(this, file)
          file.previewElement.classList.add('dz-complete')
          $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="document[]" value="' + file.file_name + '">')
        }
      @endif
    }
  }
</script>
@stop
```

This is the controller method code :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{


    foreach ($request->input('document') as $file) {
        $document = new Document();
        print_r($file);
        die();
        //$request->file('document')->move('tmp/uploads', $file);
        $document->name = $file;
        $document->save();
    }

    return Redirect::to("create")->with('success', 'Documents uploaded successfully.');
}
```

What I want is the `$file` to be an object that I can manipulate the various methods on it such as `$file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();` etc
But the problem is that it is an actual file such as `5ea264bf_image.jpg.`

Please help!

Comment: Edit your question and add the controller code.